# Magento 1.x or 2.x DB connection with MSSQL

Tags: mssql

My application is going to be developed either in Magento 1.x or 2.x as per the business requirements and approvals. What they are insisting is to host the application in Azure environment and to use MSSQL server (or Azure Cosmos DB) to connect to Magento.

I want to know is it technically possible and if yes, which specific version and do I need to write multiple custom queries (as read more and more in certain articles and which can degrade my site performance and can be stuck in future also) also will Magento wont provide further support for this?

Thanks,
Vishal